# Replace string gsub in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, directed-acyclic-graphs

how do i parse this string in R so that it will look like the following? I'm trying to do this through regular expression through `gsub()`, but not getting any luck

Input:

```
"dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}"
```

Output:

```
"D<-G;A<-D;A<-G;A<-Q"
```

I've tried:

```
gsub("dag{(.*)}","","dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}")
```

Comment: Maybe use square brackets: `gsub("dag|[{} ]","","dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this good for you ?

```
gsub(pattern = "dag|\\{|\\}|[[:space:]]", replacement = "", x = "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `stringr` you could try:

```r
str <- "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}"


library(stringr)

str_remove_all(str, "(dag)|[ {}]")
#> [1] "D<-G;A<-D;A<-G;A<-Q"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As this is a [dag format](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/directed-acyclic-graphs/info), we could use dedicated packages to import:

```
library(ggdag)
library(dagitty)

# read dag format
dag <- dag("dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}") 

dag
# dag {
# A
# D
# G
# Q
# dag
# D -> A
# G -> A
# G -> D
# Q -> A
# }

# plot
ggdag(dag) + theme_dag()
```

[image]

Comment: This makes all things simplest, cool! Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
> gsub("[(dag){} ]", "", "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}")
[1] "D<-G;A<-D;A<-G;A<-Q"
```

---

If you want to create a DAG, you can try the following code using `igraph` package

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  matrix(
    unlist(
      regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\w+", x))
    )[-1],
    ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE
  )[, 2:1]
)
```

such that

```
> g
IGRAPH 9786b7a DN-- 4 4 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 9786b7a (vertex names):
[1] G->D D->A G->A Q->A
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex find all approach which matches all the edge relationships:

```r
input <- "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}"
output <- regmatches(input, gregexpr("[A-Z]+<-\\{[A-Z]+\\}", input))[[1]]
output <- paste(gsub("[{}]", "", output), collapse=";")
output

[1] "D<-G;A<-D;A<-G;A<-Q"
```

This answer is fairly robust as it does not assume anything about the text surrounding the closure of graph edges.  Rather, it just matches the edges and then strips off the curly braces.

Comment: This would not work if they have d, a, g as node names. Try with "dag{d<-{g}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}"

Comment: @zx8754 That's an edge case, not implied by the OP's sample data, and also is trivial to fix.  We can just do a case insensitive regex search, or instead match on `[A-Za-z]+`.

Comment: OK, the input is a dag format, it starts with the word "dag", we need to match on the word, not letters, then remove curly brackets and spaces. It is very likely the nodes would have the letters d, a, g in real data.

Comment: @zx8754 Wow, it sounds like `dag` can be a real _dog_.